# EJB programmatical authentification on WildFly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, sasl

I use JBoss WildFly, Jax-Rs 2.0 and EJB 3.0.

I am trying to implement authentication by calling login method in my service.

```
@POST
@PermitAll
public Response login(AuthLoginElement al) {
    try {
        httpRequest.login(al.getUsername(), al.getPassword());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity(e.getMessage())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Also my EJB is annotated properly to WildFLy documentation.

```
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed({ "guest", "admin" })
@SecurityDomain("test-policy")
public class SecuredEJB {

public String getSecurityInfo() {
    // Session context injected using the resource annotation
    Principal principal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();

    return principal.getName();
}
```

In my `standalone.xml` I have defined security domain:

```
            <security-domain name="test-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/SecurityDS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from  PRINCIPLES where principal_id=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select user_role, 'Roles' from  ROLES where  principal_id=?"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

However after calling `httpRequest.login()`, 200 is returned but nothing happens, security logs are clears and user is not authenticated. Could you help me or suggest another way of authentication to EJB?

Comment: My guess is that you are calling the EJB in a separate request and it throws that the user is unauthenticated. Most probably the `login` does not create a session or (less probably but still an option) the subsequent request to the EJB does not return the session cookie.

Comment: I think there may be an option to create security realms but security-domains.